# Javascript is not responding to some users who use IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I am using asp.net with javascript. Javascript work fine with IE8 and some IE11. Javascript is able to response for some user who use IE11 but it doesn't response to other users who is also use IE11 even though they already have IE setting script enabled. I already update to 4.5 .NET Framework but the result still doesn't work. One of users told me that the web used to work well before while he using IE11 and he haven't change anything since until web doesn't work for him. Anyone know what could cause it?

Here is one of user who got this source error on javascript file,

[image: error source]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is in IE setting under Security tab by removing the web URL from trusted sites and move url to local intranet.